# How to correctly set the dependecies settings when generating packages

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'm relatively new to modules development on Magento 1.6.2, I have to modules :

- Company_JQueryUI (adds jqueryui + theme files to the Adminhtml heading)
- Company_Slider (A simple image slider with file upload)

These modules I made work fine on the development environment and I've been asked to generate them separately, in a way that any modules that requires JQueryUI on the backend should activate it on demand and requires it in the installation process.

I've followed the wiki page concerning the packaging phase, on the dependencies tab I've set the following :

```
Package : Company_JQueryUI
Channel : community
Min : 1.1.0
Max : 1.1.0
Files : (I really don't know whether this field is required and what should I put there, but the wiki just ignores this part.
```

All the other settings are correctly set.

The problem is that when I start the installation process of the slider module, Magento Connect doesn't generate any exception regarding the missing dependency, So I though maybe I need to set the dependency in the /etc/moduels/Company_Slider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Slider>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Company_JQueryUI />
            </depends>
        </Company_Slider>
    </modules>
</config>
```

But then I got a bigger problem, Magento Connect still ignores the dependency on the deployment phase, but once it's done, it generates an exception, and the website is put on maintenance mode, blocking any access to it, and Showing the dependency exception on a blank page (Magento Connect).

So far all I could do is remove the module files manually to get the site working again, I don't know if I'm missing something or it's a bug in the deployment process.

PS : bug resolved in 1.7